# Why won't datepicker work in a twig in userfrosting?

Tags: jquery-plugins, twig, bootstrap-datepicker, userfrosting

Bit of a beginner here and this issue has been causing me a headache for over a day.  I'm using userfrosting as a framework, with the usual twig files for the web pages.

I'm trying to include a datepicker (bootstrap-datepicker.js hasn't worked, neither is the current iteration using jquery-ui) in a form in a twig - but no matter what I do, I can't get it to work!

Here's the basic setup:

```
{% block head %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{site.uri.js}}/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{site.uri.js}}/custom.js" ></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
.... {{boring stuff missed out}}
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
.... {{boring stuff missed out}}
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="datepicker" class="col-sm-3 form-control-label">Subject Date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datepicker" />
    </div>
</div>
.... {{boring stuff missed out}}
</form>
.... {{boring stuff missed out}}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

The box is on the page, you can type a date into it etc, but nothing appears when you click on it (there should be a calendar appearing.)

Anyone have any ideas?  I'm at a total loss. I've tried various versions, locally and (as you can see, currently) on a CDN, but nothing works.  I'm sure it's probably something basic as I'm not an experienced web dev or anything, but any advice or working examples would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh! *facepalm*

Well, after some digging and serious consideration of the inspector output (thanks CTRL-SHIFT-I!) it turns out to be a simple case of script loading order and multiple scripts being loaded.

I didn't realise twig loads a whole bucketload of scripts on top of what I ask it to load in the template I was creating.  Only after seeing the inspector output for the page did I see that I was trying to load two different versions of jQuery and my own custom script was being loaded out of order - I was loading them here:

```
{% block head %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{site.uri.js}}/custom.js" ></script>
{% endblock %}
```

that block should be reserved for stylesheets.  Instead, I should be loading them here:

```
{% block page_scripts %}
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{site.uri.js}}/custom.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

... so that they are loaded AFTER all the default Bootstrap and userfrosting scripts.

Comment: Creator of UF here!  You can also load additional Javascript assets through the `PageSchema` in `initialize.php`: https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/userfrosting/initialize.php#L210-L272.  This makes it easy to assign assets to load for specific page groups, rather than loading them individually on each page.

Comment: Hi @alexw - thanks for the comment, I'll look into that as it could be a cleaner way to add the scripts I need. Thanks for UF too - has saved us a lot of work getting started! :)

Answer (score 0):

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ uses type="text" for the input field. When I google the matter it seems that type="date" has at least previously caused problems.

In short: I would try changing type="date" to type="text".

Comment: Thanks for the reply Carl - I've changed type to 'text' and it hasn't changed anything - still no response when clicking on the input box or icon. :(

Comment: Hmm. Then I'm sadly out of ideas for the moment, but would it be possible to post the resulting html (with irrelevant stuff edited out)? Then I (or more likely someone else) may be able to find what's wrong.